# SQLiteConnection: Could not change the database journal as DB was busy. Proceeding... Room Database android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I am trying to perform `write` operation in my RoomDB but its giving error
`SQLiteConnection: Could not change the database journal as DB was busy. Proceeding...`

Here is how I am trying to do:

In my `ViewModel`

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
      productsRepo.addProductInDB(Product(prodID, name))
}
```

In my `Repo`

```
suspend fun addProductInDB(product: Product) {
        appDatabase.productDao().addProduct(product)
    }
```

Here is my `product` table/entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "product_table")
class Product(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    val store: Int,
}
```

Here is my `ProductDao`

```
@Dao
interface ProductDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun addProduct(product: Product)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM product_table ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun readAllProducts(): LiveData<List<Product>>

}
```

This is my database abstract class

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Product::class), version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun productDao(): ProductDao

    // To Make AppDatabase Singleton Class
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if(tempInstance != null) {
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    AppDatabase::class.java,
                    "app_database"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But whenever I try to add product in DB it prints out in log

> SQLiteConnection: Could not change the database journal as DB was busy. Proceeding...

I am unable to find what I am doing wrong, any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Did you find a solution for this question?

Comment: @VictorReyes I changed this approach, and used dagger2 to create a singleton instance of DB